# Stub JSON.parse in RSPEC

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

I'm doing some RSPEC testing here.

If i have this method:

```
JSON.parse("https://test.com/return_json/reviews.json")
```

Then I can stub it RSPEC like:

```
test_reviews = {"reviews" => [{"data1" => "1", "data2"=> "2"}]}
allow(JSON).to receive(:parse).and_return(test_reviews.to_json)
```

But for this kind (with other method inside (`to_uri` & `read`)).

```
JSON.parse("https://test.com/return_json/reviews.json".to_uri.read)
```

I tried to used `receive_message_chain` but no success.

Thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You code is not actually calling the url you. You need to make an http call and parse the body. I should probably look like this.

```
describe :ReviewsController
  let(:uri) { URI('https://test.com/return_json/reviews.json') }
  let(:reviews) { {"reviews" => [{"data1" => "1", "data2"=> "2"}]} }

  before do 
    stub_request(:get, uri).
      with(headers: {'Accept'=>'*/*', 'User-Agent'=>'Ruby'}).
      to_return(status: 200, body: JSON.dump(reviews), headers: {})
  end

  it 'does whatever you want' do
    response = Net::HTTP.get(uri)
    expect(JSON.parse(response.body)['data1']).to eq('1') # or whatever you want to test
  end
end
```

It's better explained [here](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/how-to-stub-external-services-in-tests).